# How to edit SQL command in the pgadmin 4's create... > new column...?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I cannot edit the SQL command in my pgadmin's UI

[image].

I was following a tutorial from 2016 that has this [tutorial's pgadmin's UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViVj2.png). In the tutorial, there's a "read-only" checkbox that can be unchecked if we want to edit the SQL command (in this case I want to append `PRIMARY KEY` after `ADD COLUMN id serial`)

I'm using windows 10, pgadmin 4 in chrome browser.

Comment: SQL tab is read only, you can not edit the content, if you want to manually change anything then copy the given SQL in the query tool OR once the column is created use the Primary key constraint to create it

Comment: Thank you. I'm now using dbeaver instead of pgadmin4